# Flash AS3 - URLLoader loads last data again

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, urlloader

Okay, here is one weird bug...

In my app, I load multiple xml files. And to load those, I always create a new URLLoader. Nothing special.

The first file works fine, the second one does, too.
The third one, however, reports to have loaded fine, but the data it holds is actually the data of the second file.
The current workaround is to load the third file twice, which somehow works... weird.

I have absolutely no clue how such a thing can happen.
All three files are of course different files with different paths.

Here is the relevant class, hope it is of any use, if something is unclear, please ask.
The DownloadJob class is merely a helper class that holds a String and a Function object. The latter one is called when the download is finished.

```
    // Actual class stuff
    private var _downloadQueue  :Array = new Array();

    /**
     * Adds a download to the queue. Will be started immediatly.
     * @param   p_url       The URL of the download.
     * @param   p_callback  The function to call when the download is finished. Has to take a DisplayObject/Sound/String as first parameter.
     */
    public function addDownload(p_url:String, p_callback:Function) :void
    {
        var job :DownloadJob = new DownloadJob(p_url, p_callback);
        _downloadQueue.push(job);

        debug.ttrace("added: " + job.url);

        // If it is the only item, start downloading
        if (_downloadQueue.length == 1)
        {
            var job :DownloadJob = DownloadJob(_downloadQueue[0]);
            load(job);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Will call the callback and dispatch an event if all loading is done.
     * @param   p_event The event that is passed when a download was completed.
     */
    private function downloadComplete(p_event:Event) :void 
    {
        var job :DownloadJob = DownloadJob(_downloadQueue[0]);
        var downloaded :Object = p_event.target;
        _downloadQueue.splice(0, 1);

        debug.ttrace("completed: " + job.url);

        // Notify via callback
        if (downloaded is LoaderInfo)
        {
            job.callback(downloaded.content);
        }
        else if (downloaded is Sound)
        {
            job.callback(downloaded);
        }
        else if (downloaded is URLLoader)
        {
            // This one holds the data of the previously loaded xml, somehow
            job.callback(URLLoader(downloaded).data);
        }

        // Continue downloading if anything is left in the queue
        if (_downloadQueue.length > 0)
        {
            var job :DownloadJob = DownloadJob(_downloadQueue[0]);
            load(job);
        }
        else
        {
            dispatchEvent(new Event(EVENT_DOWNLOADS_FINISHED));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Will load the passed job immediatly.
     * @param   p_job   The job to load.
     */
    private function load(p_job:DownloadJob) :void
    {
        // Different loaders needed for data, sound and non-sound
        if (p_job.url.indexOf(".xml") != -1 ||
            p_job.url.indexOf(".txt") != -1)
        {
            var urlloader :URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            urlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, downloadComplete);
            urlloader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError);
            urlloader.load(new URLRequest(p_job.url));
        }
        else if (   p_job.url.indexOf(".mp3") != -1 &&
                    p_job.url.indexOf(".flv") != -1)
        {
            var sound :Sound = new Sound();
            sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, downloadComplete);
            sound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError);
            sound.load(new URLRequest(p_job.url));
        }
        else
        {
            var loader :Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, downloadComplete);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError);
            loader.load(new URLRequest(p_job.url));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, I found out that it works if I do NOT use a new URLLoader each time. When I use the same URLLoader for all my requests, the error is gone. That is a workaround I can live with. ... ... Still, the error confuses me. Must be some kind of memory bug in Flash.

Comment: First of all your line where you're checking to see if the file is a FLV or a MP3 is wrong. Your conditional is saying && not ||. Second, I'm not so sure you can load a FLV into a Sound class but I could be wrong. Third, can you post ALL of the code, since this code shows nothing except how you're loading, when the real issue could very well come from your URL generation which you pass to addDownload.

Comment: Thanks for the Sound hint, figured out that Sound can only load mp3 a while ago but forgot to remove this from the class.
As my above comment shows, the URL generation work correct.

Comment: Where is the DownloadJob class?

Comment: There simply must be something else wrong. Creating multiple URLLoaders should not cause that issue. I have written loaders like this and have even deployed them to massive websites with tens of millions of users... I never experienced any such bug. If it works and you're happen then I guess post your solution as an answer in a couple of days(when the system allows you) but in my opinion there is a deeper issue here.

Comment: The DownloadJob class is nothing but a struct class that has two public members and a constructor that assigns them. Nothing else in there.

Comment: Ok, see my last comment. Struct class eh... you come from a background in C/C++?

Comment: Yeah, C++. I know I could have used a simple Object, but... I didn't want to ;). Oh, I forgot to say that the loader class is a Singleton. Could that be somehow related to the problem? The Singleton is done like [link](http://www.how-to-code.com/as3-actionscript3/as3-design-patterns/as3-singleton-class.html) in all of my Singleton classes. Pretty standard, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time on your class and could not find any errors, even when dispatching random `addDownload` commands from a timer - everything went as expected, no mix-ups, no weird data residue.  I can only guess that perhaps the issue has something to do with weird variable handling in ActionScript, if it really is within the code you posted at all.

So then I took the liberty of rearranging your Class a bit:

- I changed the queue's type to `Vector.<DownloadJob>`.  This lets us get rid of all the type casting.
- The current download is stored in the field variable `currentJob`. There will only be one job to work on at a time, anyway. This eliminates all the function arguments.
- A job will only be added to the queue, if `currentJob` isn't `null`, i.e. a download is actually in progress. We don't have to queue things, if there's no need to wait. This leaves only a single call to each `push()` and `splice()`. No more uncertainties in respect to when things get added and removed.
- Removed hungarian notation (we don't do that in ActionScript).
- Split your larger methods into smaller, more readable chunks (helps me think :) ).
- Removed all the comments, except for the API method (the code should speak for itself, I believe).

Try to exchange the code below with your previous class and see if the problem still exists.  If it does, I am pretty sure the problem exists outside of your loader, possibly in the callback functions that process the payload.

```
private static const EVENT_DOWNLOADS_FINISHED : String = "EVENT_DOWNLOADS_FINISHED";
private var currentJob : DownloadJob;
private var downloadQueue : Vector.<DownloadJob> = new Vector.<DownloadJob> ();

/**
 * Adds a download to the queue. Will be started immediatly.
 * @param   url       The URL of the download.
 * @param   callback  The function to call when the download is finished. Has to take a DisplayObject/Sound/String as first parameter.
 */
 public function addDownload ( url : String, callback : Function ) : void {
    var job : DownloadJob = new DownloadJob ( url, callback );
    if (currentJob) downloadQueue.push ( job );
    else {
        currentJob = job;
        load ();
    }
}

private function load () : void {
    if ( jobIsText () ) loadText ();
    else if ( jobIsSound () ) loadSound ();
}

private function jobIsText () : Boolean {
    var url : String = currentJob.url;
    return url.indexOf ( ".xml" ) != -1 || url.indexOf ( ".txt" ) != -1;
}

private function jobIsSound () : Boolean {
    var url : String = currentJob.url;
    return url.indexOf ( ".mp3" ) != -1;
}

private function loadText () : void {
    var urlloader : URLLoader = new URLLoader ();
    urlloader.addEventListener ( Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete );
    urlloader.addEventListener ( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError );
    urlloader.load ( new URLRequest ( currentJob.url ) );
}

private function loadSound () : void {
    var sound : Sound = new Sound ();
    sound.addEventListener ( Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete );
    sound.addEventListener ( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError );
    sound.load ( new URLRequest ( currentJob.url ) );
}

private function handleComplete ( ev : Event ) : void {
    processPayload ( ev.target );

    if (downloadQueue.length > 0) loadNext ();
    else dispatchEvent ( new Event ( EVENT_DOWNLOADS_FINISHED ) );
}

private function handleError ( ev : Event ) : void {
    trace ( "Error while downloading:" + currentJob.url );
}

private function processPayload ( loader : Object ) : void {
    currentJob.callback ( getPayload ( loader ) );
    currentJob = null;
}

private function loadNext () : void {
    currentJob = downloadQueue.splice ( 0, 1 )[0];
    load ();
}

private function getPayload ( loader : Object ) : Object {
    return (loader is LoaderInfo) ? loader.content :     
               (loader is URLLoader) ? URLLoader ( loader ).data :
                   loader;
}
```

Comment: That one is actually not possible, as the class loads only one item at a time. Always the first one. And the debugger shows that all items are loaded in order.

Comment: You were right - in fact, your code worked quite well for me...  Anyway, I edited my answer. See if this helps finding the problem.

Comment: Whoa, you seriously put a lot effort into this! .... and turned my nice commented and styled code into ... that stuff ;) Really, I had to laugh at the "we don't do that in ActionScript" :D... If you look at the comments above, I already found a workaround by using one single URLLoader. But since you put such an effort into helping me, I'll try that one out, too and report back :)

Comment: Okay, tried it out and it works. Won't use it directly as the style is just too vastly different from the rest, but I'll take the usage of the Vector class. Of course, the error remains a mystery, but I don't have the time to dig deeper, unfortunately. I declare this an official solution! *trumpets*

Comment: *bows* It's been a pleasure :)  Seriously - the hungarian notation stuff is a relic from the days when we had no syntax highlighting and code hints. ;) Check out http://www.amazon.com/dp/0132350882/?tag=stackoverfl08-20, resp. http://cleancoders.com/ - Bob Martin had a giant impact on my professional life...

Comment: Thing is, no matter the highlighting and helpers your IDE offers. A _ in front of a variable tells you it is a private/protected member. A "p_" tells, you it was a parameter from the function. Etc., etc. It does so in all IDEs without even having to hover your mouse anywhere. In your code, for example, there would be no telling if "currentJob" belongs to the class, is a parameter or a temporary variable from inside the function.

Comment: Of course, in your code it doesn't make that much of a difference, but in bigger functions, you'll reach a point where you ask yourself that question. And I really don' like writing "this."  in front of everything ;) And some people prefer to work with IDEs that may not offer whatever **you** are used to. In the end, it is the only thing that works for everyone, is easy to understand, easy to write and is always helpful.

Comment: And I forgot to say that code assist shows me all items that belong to the class whenever I type a _ as the first character. Pretty helpful ;)

Comment: I do the underscore for private fields, too. Everything else... well, your functions shouldn't be that long in the first place. Nor should your classes. But you're right: To each his/her own. I still recommend you check out Uncle Bob - he's the real deal.